# Handling multiple observable and returning a value

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

i have a code below.

```
loadAll$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.action$.pipe(
        ofType(LOAD_ALL),
        switchMap(() => {
            
            const localDBCount = from(this.personDBService.countData())
            const localDBList = from(this.personDBService.getAll())
            const serviceList = this.personService.fetchAll();

            forkJoin([localDBCount, localDBList, serviceList]).pipe(
                map(results => {
                    if (results[0] > 0) {
                        //return the list
                        return LOAD_ALL_SUCCESS({ list: results[1] })
                    } else {
                        return LOAD_ALL_SUCCESS({ list: results[2] })
                    }
                })
            )

        }), catchError(err => {
            return of(LOAD_ALL_FAILED({ error: err }))
        })
    )
})
```

My Goal is when the LOAD_ALL action is called then in this effect method. It will check if there are some data or at least 1 data present in indexDB if there is then return the action **LOAD_ALL_SUCCESS**

else call the rest api then return the action **LOAD_ALL_SUCCESS** with the data got from the api

I'm getting an error on the switchMap which is expecting a return and I couldn't come up with a solution on this. I know formJoin joins the observables but not sure how to return a value.

Also all methods from the **personDBService** return Promises so i converted it to Observable using the **from** operator.

Error

Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: TypedAction<"[PERSON] Load All">, index: number) => ObservableInput'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.

```
21             switchMap(() => {
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to return the `forkJoin` statement within the `switchMap` block, as the type signature of `switchMap` requires you to return an observable

```
loadAll$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.action$.pipe(
        ofType(LOAD_ALL),
        switchMap(() => {
            
            const localDBCount = from(this.personDBService.countData())
            const localDBList = from(this.personDBService.getAll())
            const serviceList = this.personService.fetchAll();

            return forkJoin([localDBCount, localDBList, serviceList]).pipe(
                map(results => {
                    if (results[0] > 0) {
                        //return the list
                        return LOAD_ALL_SUCCESS({ list: results[1] })
                    } else {
                        return LOAD_ALL_SUCCESS({ list: results[2] })
                    }
                })
            )

        }), catchError(err => {
            return of(LOAD_ALL_FAILED({ error: err }))
        })
    )
});
```

Alternatively, a cleaner way of doing things would be to remove the use of nested pipes. This can be done by returning the observables from the `forkJoin`, and handle the returning of the respective actions down the primary pipeline through the `map` operator:

```
loadAll$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.action$.pipe(
        ofType(LOAD_ALL),
        switchMap(() => {            
            const localDBCount = from(this.personDBService.countData())
            const localDBList = from(this.personDBService.getAll())
            const serviceList = this.personService.fetchAll();

            return forkJoin([localDBCount, localDBList, serviceList])
        }),
        map((results) => {
          if (results[0] > 0) {
                        //return the list
            return LOAD_ALL_SUCCESS({ list: results[1] })
          } else {
            return LOAD_ALL_SUCCESS({ list: results[2] })
          }
        }),            
    )
})
```

Comment: hi this works, no syntax error anymore.. but i got a different error now.. related to the indexDB